# Image transition on hover

Tags: html, css, transform

I am having two different issues. The first is really irritating. I am attempting to align the text with the image inside of the first box, so that they are side-by-side an inline fashion. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I do not want to use floats.

Secondly, I am attempting to get the image to `transform: translate` on the x-axis on hover. The thing is, I want the image to `transform` on the `.extra-box:hover`...not on the actual image, but I only want the image to move. I cannot figure this out.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
#extra {
 margin: 25px auto;
 width: 460px;
 height: auto;
}
.extra-box {
 position: relative;
 width: 40%;
 padding: 8px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 /*border: 1px solid #739BAF;*/
 border: 2px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 background: none;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.extra-box:hover {
 border: 2px solid red;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.extra-box:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 40%;
 margin-right: 10%;
}
.extra-box:last-child {
 width: 40%;
}
.extra-box a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.extra-box-text {
 color: black;
 font-size: 1em;
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
}
.extra-box-icon img {
 padding-left: 5px;
 width: 15px;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transition: all .5 ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5 ease-in-out;
 /*transform: translateX(30px);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);*/
}
```

```html
  <div id="extra"><div class="extra-box">
    <a href="contact">
     <div class="extra-box-text">Need help?<br>Contact Us Now</div><div class="extra-box-icon"><img src="icons/right-arrow.png"></div>
    </a>
   </div><div class="extra-box">
    <a href="register">
     <div class="extra-box-text">Need an account?<br>Register Now</div>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Remove padding-left on .extra-box-icon img for image to be aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers pointed out, you were missing a display: inline-block, but the problem was in .extra-box-icon

I have also added the transform for the image: (See the beginning of the CSS)

```css
.extra-box-icon {
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  transition: transform 1s;  
}
.extra-box:hover img {
    transform: translateX(-100px);  
}
#extra {
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 460px;
  height: auto;
}
.extra-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*border: 1px solid #739BAF;*/
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.extra-box:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.extra-box:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.extra-box:last-child {
  width: 40%;
}
.extra-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.extra-box-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
.extra-box-icon img {
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 15px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .5 ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5 ease-in-out;
  /*transform: translateX(30px);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);*/
}
```

```html
<div id="extra">
  <div class="extra-box">
    <a href="contact">
      <div class="extra-box-text">Need help?
        <br>Contact Us Now</div>
      <div class="extra-box-icon">
        <img src="icons/right-arrow.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="extra-box">
    <a href="register">
      <div class="extra-box-text">Need an account?
        <br>Register Now</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get the image to fade over to the end position instead of just snapping into place? I tried doing this: `transform: translateX(30px);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
 -webkit-transition: all .5 ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5 ease-in-out;`

Comment: Add the transtion to the base element. I have added it on the snippet

Comment: Wouldn't `.extra-box:hover img` be the base? I do not want to assign it to a blank img tag.

Comment: You can use .extra-box img then

Comment: Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top;` in **.extra-box** class to align it to same level.

Answer (score 0):

to fix the alignment issue and if you don't want to use float, you can change the display property of .extra-box-text and extra-box-text img to inline-block

```
.extra-box-text, .extra-box-text img{
    display:inline-block;
    width: /*adjust as needed*/ 
}
```

to deal with the animation, i suggest you set the image itself as a background of .extra-box, you would then change the background-position on hover

Hope this helps

Comment: I already have them set as `display: inline-block`. Thanks though.